# Speed shows 100.0 Mbps but why not 1.0 Gbps?

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet

I have a very simple setup.  A Verizon Fios Actiontec MI424WR going to my Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC.  For some reason my speed is shown as 100.0 Mbps.  Why doesn't it show 1.0 Gbps?  The cable?

Answer (score 13):

Quoting directly from [The Manual](http://support.actiontec.com/doc_files/MI424WR_Rev._ACD_User_Manual_4.0.16.1.56.0.10.11.x_v6.pdf) (for the latest MI424WR Verizon is shipping):

> LAN Ethernet Ports (4)
>   The LAN Ethernet ports connect devices to the FiOS Router via Ethernet cables 
>   to create a local area network (LAN). The LAN Ethernet ports are 10/100 Mbps 
>   auto-sensing ports, and either a straight-through or crossover Ethernet cable 
>   can be used when connecting devices to the ports.

The LAN ports are NOT gigabit - they are 10/100.